# Hide and show div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a div which is easily done with hide function in jquery. But it is not working.The div is

```
<div id="antivirusAlertDiv">
            <ul class="shielding_elements">
                <li>
                    <%= Html.RadioButton("antivirusAlertType", 0, antivirusAlertType == AntivirusAlertType.AlertMe ? true : false)%>
                    <label for="id_4">
                        Alert Me</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.RadioButton("antivirusAlertType", 0, antivirusAlertType == AntivirusAlertType.DonotAlert ? true : false)%>
                    <label for="id_5">
                        Don’t Alert</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

jquery code is:

```
function ShowAndHide(id, state) {
        var $mydiv = $('#antivirusAlertDiv');
        if (state == false) {
            $mydiv.hide().html('');
            //  $('#uniform-antivirusAlertType').hide();
          //  $('#antivirusAlertDiv .shielding_elements li').hide();
            // $("input[name='antivirusAlertType']").attr("disabled","disabled");
            //                $("#" + id).addClass("hide");
            //                $("#" + id).removeClass("show");
        }
        else {
                  $mydiv.show();
            //$('#uniform-antivirusAlertType').show();
           // $('#antivirusAlertDiv .shielding_elements li').show();
            //$("input[name='antivirusAlertType']").removeAttr("disabled");
            //                $("#" + id).removeClass("hide");
            //                $("#" + id).addClass("show");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I missing it, or are you not actually binding an event anywhere?

Comment: also, you're setting the html to nothing; when that's shown again there will be nothing there to show. (why are you removing the html??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle). However, you need to actually *bind* it to some event. For example, if the HTML looked like this:

```
<button id="clickme">Click to toggle</button>

<div id="antivirusAlertDiv">
    <!-- snip -->
</div>
```

Then in a [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery3),

```
$('#clickme').click(function ()
{
    $('#antivirusAlertDiv').toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/rPYLK/

---

***N.B.*** you can simplify the existing code as follows:

```
<div id="antivirusAlertDiv">
    <ul class="shielding_elements">
        <li>
            <label>
                <%= Html.RadioButton("antivirusAlertType", 0, antivirusAlertType == AntivirusAlertType.AlertMe)%>
                Alert Me
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <%= Html.RadioButton("antivirusAlertType", 0, antivirusAlertType == AntivirusAlertType.DonotAlert)%>
                Don’t Alert
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

- The conditional operator is redundant
- Wrap the `<label>` around the corresponding input and the `for` attribute can be omitted